# Using different conditions for a count in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, count

Hope this question makes sense.

I have a table with a field that has many populated, and many not populated.
I'm trying to get the details of what is and isn't populated (by not populated it could be Null, -, 0 or just blank)

I have put together code that gives me what I need:

```
select count(Col_A),
       count(Col_B), 
       count(case when (Col_B = '0' or Col_B is NULL or Col_B = '-' or
                        Col_B = 'NA' or Col_B = '') then 1
                  else null
             end) as Zero_Col_B_Count,
```

[image]

However I have a 3rd column which is a short code for each US state.
What I am trying to do is get the output from the above statement, but split the above out by state, I'm hoping to return something like this:

[image]

Obviously not just stopping at 2!!

I can find a few ideas around this, such as case when or while loops, but not sure how I can feed in my list of state codes to either to iterate through the task

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to group the results by the state column and get the counts for each state. You can achieve this using the GROUP BY clause in your SQL query. Assuming your table structure has columns Col_A, Col_B, and State, you can modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT State,
   COUNT(Col_A) AS Col_A_Count,
   COUNT(Col_B) AS Col_B_Count,
   COUNT(CASE
             WHEN (Col_B = '0' OR Col_B IS NULL OR Col_B = '-' OR Col_B = 'NA' OR Col_B = '') THEN 1
             ELSE NULL
         END) AS Zero_Col_B_Count
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY State;
```

This query will group the results by the State column and calculate the counts for each state. The ORDER BY clause is optional, but it will sort the results by the state codes in ascending order. Replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table.

Comment: Ah I knew it would be something a lot easier than I had in my head! Never thought of looking at the obvious!!!

This did exactly what was required, thanks for the help!